# Targeting a checkbox and removing it with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to teach myself JQuery and Javascript. I've created a shopping list webapp that uses JQuery to add li items with checkbox inputs to html.

Heres the code for that:

```
if(item.length < 1) {
        alert("Tell us what you need")
    } else {
        $("#list").append( "<li><input type='checkbox' value='None' id='checkbox' name='check' />" + 
            "<label for='checkbox'>" + item + "</label></li>");
        $("#input").val("");
        console.log("clear")
    };
```

What I would like is remove any li items that are checked when a user clicks the #clear button. I have researched this, but have been unable to come up with a solution that only removes the checked items.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: `id`'s should be 100% unique. Use a class

Comment: @RUJordan are you talking about the #list id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
To remove, you can do something like:

```
$("#checkbox:checked").parent("li").remove();
```

Edit: as someone said you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id`. Change it to a class and use something like:

```
$(".checkbox:checked").parent("li").remove();
```

instead. The `"li"` isn't technically necessary if all checkboxes are direct children of `li`, and is probably less efficient, but might be less likely to break things depending on your page(s).

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to clear them on the click of a button so the full answer would be the following:

Comment: $("#clear").click(function() {
  $("#checkbox:checked").parent("li").remove();
 });

Comment: Just don't forget what's been said about using ids. They're intended for use with a single unique element on the page, whereas you will presumably be able to have any number of checkboxes. So your code `"<li><input type='checkbox' value='None' id='checkbox' name='check' />"` isn't standards compliant and should probably be `"<li><input type='checkbox' value='None' class='checkbox' name='check' />"` and in that case you'd also want to change `#checkbox` to `.checkbox` in your full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(':checked').remove()
```

This will remove all checked checkboxes.

Comment: keyword `all`. You might want to target a little bit more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your task, you need remove each one element of list, if his input-child is not checked after change?

```
$("#list").on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code works for removing the li item upon checking the box, however, I'm looking to remove checked items when a button is clicked (#clear).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$("[name=check]:checked").remove();
```